# Microsoft Unit Testing: How to connect to database

Tags: c#, oracle, unit-testing

I have a dll that I am building that inserts, updates and selects from an oracle database. I have a development database set up that I can use which has packages that I am sending data to.   I want to use the Microsoft Unit testing to connect to this database and verify that the code in working. But I can't get the connection to the database setup.  Been searching for information on how to do this for a while...any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: How are you currently trying to connect to the database? We can give you guidance if we have a better idea of where you're getting stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's not recommended to use "Unit Test" as a terminology to connect to databases and perform tests. However, it is entirely possible to do that which IMO amounts to abuse of the "Unit Test" terminology.
You must first understand that a unit test is supposed to be used to test a unit of code in isolation of all it's dependencies. That is, you first isolate your code from all the dependent systems using test stubs, mocks or whatever you fancy and then perform your test against that code. http://www.unit-testing.net/ is a pretty useful guide to understand unit testing concepts.
Now coming back to your question. It is definitely possible to integrate with your development database (assuming it's Oracle) and run unit test against your code that connects to this database. 
You will need to reference Oracle.DataAccess after installing ODP from Oracle. (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html)
After that, you can simply do:

```
    var con = new OracleConnection(); 
    con.ConnectionString = "User Id=<username>;Password=<password>;Data Source= <datasource>"; 
    con.Open();
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight on the "Unit Testing". The company I work for has always used that verbiage.  Glad to recognize that its not really correct. I did just solve my issue before seeing your response.  What I needed to do was create an app config file for my test project and add the connection string in it.  That works for my code base....My question was not formed as well as it could of been.  Thanks for the input on the terminology! I will make sure to correct my thought process on this.